# Highcharts and JSON parameters

Tags: json, highcharts

My file data.json is :

```
[{"metier":"Administratif","total":197555},
{"metier":"Canalisateur","total":4717},
{"metier":"Carreleur","total":15513}]
```

Please let me know how can i write my javascript code ? 
I would like to create a chart with column ("metier" is X and "total" is Y)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Could you specify what your javascript should achieve and what is going wrong exactly? This not a very clear question

Comment: You need to parse your data, by loops and prepare structure like {name:'aaa', y: 20}, where 'aaa' and 20 will be get from your json.

Comment: I would like to create a chart with column ("metier" is X and "total" is Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example of parser:

var output = [];

```
$.each(data,function(i,d){
    output.push({
        name: d.metier,
        y: d.total
    });
});
```

This code needs to be run in $.getJSON() callback body.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/g7uzzyka/1/

Comment: I use this code but it doesn't work :-(   `   var output = [];
 
   $.getJSON('data.json', function(i,d) { 
      output.push({
      name: d.metier,
      y: d.total
        });
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart:{
            type:'column'
        },
        xAxis:{
            type:'category'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: output
        }]
    });`

Comment: Why you remove loop ($each) I mean

Comment: I change my code but it doesn't work : ` $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        var output = [];

        $.each(data,function(i,d){
            output.push({
                name: d.metier,
                y: d.total
            });
        });

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart:{
                type:'column'
            },
            xAxis:{
                type:'category'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: output
            }]
        });


    }); `

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console ? (I mean developer tools console).

Comment: It mean that your data.json is incorrect file, or have any illegal mark.

Comment: finally, It's work ! It's because I used an old highcharts.js" in local. Thanks for your help ! :-)